# Unable to upload data from excel to mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, file-handling

I am new to PHP and am trying to upload data from excel to database using PHP .I Have the following code to upload the data from a .xls file to mysql database using php. The code works fine except that it does not assign the first coloun of first row to the array although the code is able to access and print it in table. Need help read the first element too.
Below is the code assuming we have an excel file named example.xls.

```
   <?php
    require 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
    require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    //  $host = 'localhost';
    //  $username = 'root';
    //  $password = 'root';
    //  $dbname = 'dumy';
    //  $conn=mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("Could not connect");
    //  mysql_select_db($dbname,$conn) or die("could not connect database");
    $path = "example.xls";
    $queryArray = array();
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);
    $flag=true;
    foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
        $worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();
        if($flag)
        {
            $highestRow         = 0;
            $highestColumn      = 'A';
            $flag= false;
        }
        $curRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); 
        $curColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(''); 
        $curColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($curColumn);
        $highestRow = ($highestRow<$curRow)?$curRow:$highestRow;
        $highestColumn = ($highestColumn<=$curColumn)?$curColumn:$highestColumn;
        $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
        $nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;
        echo "<br>The worksheet ".$worksheetTitle." has ";
        echo $nrColumns . ' columns (A-' . $highestColumn . ') ';
        echo ' and ' . $curRow . ' row.';
        echo '<br>Data: <table border="1"><tr>';
        for ($row = 1; $row <= $curRow;$row++) {
            echo '<tr>';
            for ($col = 0; $col < $curColumnIndex; $col++) {
                $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
                $val = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
                $queryArray[$row][$col] = (string)$val;
                echo '<td>'.$val.'<br></td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
    }   
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO Dummy VALUES';
        $value = NULL;
        foreach($queryArray as $v)
        {   
            $value .=  '(';
            foreach ($v as $check)  
                $value .= '\''.$check.'\',';
            $value = substr($value,0,-1);
            $value .= '),';
        }
        $sql.=substr($value,0,-1).';';
        echo $sql;
        //mysql_query($sql) or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());

    ?>
```

Comment: I think you should convert xls format into csv. Try that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have more than one iteration that leads to multiple sheets in same array.

```
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) { }.
```

So, if your excel contains more than one sheet and the next sheet have no data means blank then it count it as first and insert it to you first value of the array.
If you use this array outside of the loop then it will show you the null value in first column.
Use this SQL inside the foreach loop and to prevent the use of excessive memory you can opt for redeclaration of array at every iteration of loop. It will work fine for you.

> ```
> foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
>   $queryArray = array();
>   // your code as it was
>   $sql = 'INSERT INTO Dummy VALUES';
>   $value = NULL;
>   foreach($queryArray as $v)
>   {
>       $value .=  '(';
>       foreach ($v as $check)
>           $value .= '\''.$check.'\',';
>       $value = substr($value,0,-1);
>       $value .= '),';
>   }
>   $sql.=substr($value,0,-1).';';
>   //mysql_query($sql) or die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem of both PHP and excel. That it doesn't pick the value of 1 column and 1 row that means the first value of excel sheet.

Like if your excel appears like below

```
___________________
|  10|  test|  205|
|  11|  test|  206|
|  12|  test|  207|
|  13|  test|  208|
```

Then it will not pick the "10", else all values will be picked.

Can't help but this is how it works.

Please let me know if any one has a solution.

Answer (score -1):

You start with $row=1, that might be it.

Comment: here we use one because the Row are numbered from 1 in excel not 0.

Comment: Can you try `print_r($queryArray)` to see if it's correctly constructed?

Comment: I tried this and thus observed that the code is not able to store the value of the first element in the array.